# Change shape color in Highmaps programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I have a map made with Highmaps library, made up of two series: admin boundaries and cities.
On its side there is a list of all the admins, and on each of this item there is a mouse hover event attached.
I'm trying to **highlight without selecting** the relative shape on the map when the mouse is over the admin text.
I've been able to make it with the *select* function of highmaps, but I can't use it anymore as I've also enable multiselection and I'm using it for other purposes.

So what I'm trying to do is to **manually/programmatically change the color** of a particular point in the series.

here is the code executed in the mouseover event on the list item

```
$( "ul#admins li" ).mouseover(function() {
   var adminCode = $(this).attr('id')); //retrieve the adminCode
   var chart = $('#mapContainer').highcharts();
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
       if (chart.series[0].data[i].Code == adminCode) {
           //I've got the map element to highlight...
           //..but how I can do change its color?

           //before I was using this method, selecting directly, but now
           //I don't want to select it, only change its color.
           chart.series[0].data[i].select(true, false);
           break;
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you please post live example of your issue? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński sorry unfortunately the application is still under development and very huge. The issue is located in a very small of it. Putting on jsFiddle is very hard and complex at the moment. But who knows the Highmaps component for sure can identify the issue and knows how to solve it

Comment: I think that you should be able to use Point.update() in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/x14dm93u/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks! It works. In the night I've found also this (by inspecting the svg rendering): chart.series[0].data[1].graphic.attr({ fill: '#7CB5EC' }); that is working fine on my app but not in your fiddle example. I think they should do the same thing, but your solution is more clear and the right way to do it. If you put it as answer I will accept so we share also to other

Comment: It is good idea to use graphic.attr() as well. The problem with this solution may be when you are changing your point state (like hovering points and then mouseleaving it)

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I have implemented the Point.update() on my maps which are more complex than the one of the example and I've found very bad performance, UI becomes almost unresponsive. I've checked with the JS Profiler of Chrome and the result is that the dSetter function of Highmaps takes around 3~4 seconds to set the attribute eating 40% of CPU. chart.series[0].data[1].graphic.attr() instead has not this problem. very strange

Comment: are you changing more than just one point in your map at once? if yes, you should not redraw your chart on every update

Comment: you're right, I have cycle through all the points series to restore their original color. Using Point.update({color: '#1F6EBC'},false) and then chart.redraw(); works much better, but still slower than using the direct set of the graphic.attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Point.update() for changing the color of specific country in your map:

```
function(chart) {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      chart.series[1].data[0].update({
        color: 'red'
      })
    })
}
```

For example here I am changing the color of first point from your map series.

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/x14dm93u/